# OS X Maps app, seek with longitude and lattude possible?

Tags: macos, maps

Is there some way to get the Maps app in OS X Mavericks to show a specific known latitude/longitude expressed in numbers only? If so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me with the following syntax:

```
51.10N,17.02E
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll remember that syntax. Unfortunately, the coordinates I had were in a number only form. I tried to convert these but failed.

Comment: @MiB Can You show Your input?